# Запрос рядов в бд, 1 из параметр которых начинается с символов

Tags: sqlite, android, select, sql

В базе данных лежат строки типа

```
"2,2,1,2"
"1,2,3,1"
"2,2,3,5"
```

Как получить ряды, которые начинаются со строк "2,2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У меня ощущение, что у вас как-то не совсем правильно организована структура БД. Но если все-таки приходиться делать такую выборку, то наверно так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` LIKE '2,2%'
```

P.S. Если поле у вас FULLTEXT, то можно еще так попробовать:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE MATCH (`field_name`) AGAINST ('2,2*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Еще пока она никак не организована. Просто параметров может быть сколько угодно, а не 4.

Comment: @linya, Про это я и говорю. Может быть имеет смысл параметры хранить не строкой, а по отдельности в другой таблице?

Comment: Честно говоря слабо представляю ,как это должно выглядеть. Этот ряд абсолютно упорядочен, но сколько у него цифр не известно.И собирать их из другой таблицы мне кажется более затратной операцией. Как будет быстрее ? Если есть примерная литература по данному вопросу , буду благодарен.

Comment: Так как вы не описали задачу подробно, то приходиться играть в "угадай мелодию". Могу предположить и описать в абстрактном примере:
Есть таблица товаров и таблица цветовых решений для товара. Если у вас есть товар "труселя" и вы в той же таблице, в соседнем поле будете хранить идентификатор цвета "красные", а потом искать так, как собирались, то это уж точно будет очень затратно и я вас не рекомендую делать таким образом.